# Lumen Api deployement return 500 Internal Server Error

Tags: laravel, web-deployment, lumen

I  develop a Laravel Api in local it's work, when I deploy I have a `error 500`.

- I copied the folder to the server.
- I moved the public folder to root and changed the path in `index.php`.
- I modify the file .env with the prod value.

With I test with postman my route `https://my-domain/public/api/v1/mytest` : I have a error 500.

What did i miss ?

Comment: 500 is the most generic error you can get. Check your logs

Comment: I have not logs in storage/logs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolve this problem.
The version lumen in dev and prod was different. I upgraded the dev version (5.8) to be in phase with the server (8.x) and it's work !

Answer (score 0):

Please be sure you have followed all the steps. I assume you do not use a subdomain.

1. Move your zipped project to a folder in the server (e.x. /home/mollusk/project)
2. Unzip the project
3. After unzipping your project, move everything under public folder into public_html folder (e.x. /home/mollusk/public_html)
4. Edit index.php under public_html folder changing

```
$app = require __DIR__.'/../bootstrap/app.php';
```

to

```
$app = require __DIR__.'/../project/bootstrap/app.php';
```

5. Give your domain name as value to APP_URL variable in .env file

```
APP_URL=https://my-domain
```

Comment: yes, these changes were made

Comment: Then you need to observe your htaccess, it may be the root of your problem

Comment: Please refer to this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64052457/laravel-lumen-internal-server-error-500-using-shared-hosting